# React: How to update 2d array in loop by one click?

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, setstate

I'm new to React and want to update 2d array in loop by one click.
The implementation that I want is like below

1. Loop 2d array
2. Each element in loop, color that element by yellow (it means rendering is needed)
3. This process has to be delayed per coloring

However, `setState` of React is asynchronous and batched at once, so I used `setTimeout` but it isn't working.
How can I solve this problem. Here is my code and codesandbox link

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(Array(10).fill(Array(10).fill(null)));

  const onClick = () => {
    const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board));
    board.forEach((row, ridx) => {
      row.forEach((col, cidx) => {
        copy[ridx][cidx] = "yellow";
        setTimeout(setBoard(copy), 1000 * (ridx + cidx));
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {board.map((row, ridx) => (
        <div key={ridx} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {row.map((col, cidx) => {
            const bgColor = board[ridx][cidx];
            return (
              <div
                style={{
                  width: "64px",
                  height: "64px",
                  border: "1px solid black",
                  backgroundColor: bgColor
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
          <br />
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={onClick}>START</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit 2d rendering]

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is - run the for loops instantly and change the board value to yellow for all cells. The next time (and every time) the setBoard is called, the board is already yellow.

What you might want to change is - update each cell of board inside the `setTimeout`.

One of the ways you could do is:

```
  function updateBoard(board, row, col) {
    if (col >= board[row].length) {
      row++;
      col = 0;
    }
    board[row][col] = "yellow";
    setBoard(board);

    if(row >= board.length-1 && col >= board[0].length-1) {
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      updateBoard(board, row, ++col);
    }, 1000);
  }
```